# Why is the following onclick function not executing?

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to pass four arguments event, $row['title'], $row['username'] and $row['date'].

```
<?php
echo "<script>
  function increasevotes(e,location,user,date)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(\"Hi!\");
  }
  </script>";

//I've proper code here for fetching the mySQL query results into $rows and that part is working perfectly.

while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
if($rows['public']=="yes")
{echo "<span class=\"right\" id=\"nolikes\">{$rows['vote']}</span><a href=\"\" onclick=\"increasevotes(event,\"{$rows['title']}\",\"{$rows['username']}\",\"{$rows['date']}\")\"><img src=\"img/like.png\" class=\"right\" width=\"30\" height=\"30\"/></a>";
}
?>
```

What is actually being done, is the page is being refreshed instead.
When I click view source page, this is shown:

```
<span class="right" id="nolikes">0</span>
<a href="" onclick="increasevotes(event,"chennai","venkat","01/07/2017")"><img src="img/like.png" class="right" width="30" height="30"/>
</a>
```

Comment: if you put in a console.log('Script is running'); before your function so it will run when the page is loaded... Do you see the message?

Comment: inspect element that anchor tag and you will find why is it  not working

Comment: Ids have to be unique

Answer (score 1):

Change **double quotes** of function parameter to **single quotes**

```
onclick="increasevotes(event,'chennai','venkat','01/07/2017')"
```

or use `\` to escape the quotes.